# Как очистить $_SESSION

Tags: php

Не нашел способа как очистить. При отладке использую активно.

```
unset($_SESSION); // не работает

$_SESSION['tests'][...] = ...;
unset($_SESSION['tests']); // вариант конечно, но есть свои недостатки..
```

Еще идеи какие-нибудь есть?

п.с. пока использую

```
$_SESSION = []; // выдает ошибку, но потом когда закомментишь - очищено получается
```

**Вот какое решение устроило меня на Yii:**

```
foreach ( array_keys($_SESSION) as $key => $value ) {
    if ( $key >= 5) {              // первые 5 элементов нужны
        //unset($_SESSION[$key]);  // не работает, хотя кое-где используют http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#clear-detail
        unset($_SESSION[$value]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Идей нет, есть стандартная функция очищающая все переменные в сессии:
[session_unset()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-unset.php).

Полный список функций для работы с сессиями в PHP вы найдете в [официальной документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.session.php).

Comment: тоже самое что $_SESSION = []; (т.е. ошибка)

Comment: @VitalikZ Ошибку напишите.

Comment: я использую yii. видимо там есть элементы, которые не надо удалять. т.е. надо очистить все элементы кроме некоторых

Comment: @VitalikZ В Yii есть [CHttpSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession)

Answer (score 2):

> Автор: я использую yii

Решение для Yii Framework

```
Yii::app()->session->destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-destroy.php) рекомендуют так:

```
// сбросить все переменные сессии
$_SESSION = array();

// сбросить куки, к которой привязана сессия
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

// уничтожить сессию
session_destroy();
```